# ANT Modify property in ini file

Tags: ant, ini

I have an ini file that i should add a new value to it
the ini file looks like:

```
osgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/workspace95
osgi.framework=file\:plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.9.0.v20130529-1710.jar
equinox.use.ds=true
```

I want to access this file via ANT task and to add to it a new property to be as follow:

```
osgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/workspace95
osgi.framework=file\:plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.9.0.v20130529-1710.jar
osgi.usesTimeout=1
equinox.use.ds=true
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ant target you could say something like:

```
.
.
<echo message="${line.separator}equinox.use.ds=true" file="${build.dir}/tmp.tmp"/>

        <concat destfile="${build.dir}/new.ini" append="true">
            <fileset file="${build.dir}/my.ini"/>
            <fileset file="${build.dir}/tmp.tmp"/>
        </concat>

        <delete file="${build.dir}/tmp.tmp"/>
.
.
```

assuming, your initial set of properties file is stored in build.dir/my.ini